# Xcode 8 IOS 10 libgdx roboVM app not launching on simulator

Tags: libgdx, ios-simulator, ios10, xcode8, robovm

I built my app with libgdx and for the IOS portion I am currently using MobiDevelop's fork of roboVM v2.2.1-SNAPSHOT. However when I try to launch my app on the simulator it throws this error when it tries to open the app.

```
Failed to launch application. Error Domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "The request to open "com.GGI.uParty.IOSLauncher" failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The request to open "com.GGI.uParty.IOSLauncher" failed., BSErrorCodeDescription=RequestDenied, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f80a2e5ebd0 {Error Domain=FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)" UserInfo={BSErrorCodeDescription=Unspecified}}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace) for reason: Unspecified.}
```

What does this error mean? How can I fix it? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Please file a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com, including ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone having this same issue make sure you are using Mobidevelop's fork of RoboVM currently 2.2.1-SNAPSHOT. Also do not use the iPhone 5 in your simulator. That was the only device I was getting this error on.